# Customising the system locale’s date format in recent macOS versions

Tags: calendar, internationalization, customization, clock

It used to be possible to freely customize the system date format in Mac OS preferences up to some 10.x version with a nice and flexible editor.
[image: screenshot old OS version]

In current Ventura, there’s only a selection of predefined formats and only for the short version.
[image: Ventura screenshot]

In Shortcuts, for instance, (almost) all [placeholders from UTS #35](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) can be used, so internal support is there, of course.

Is there some hidden way to still customize the formats? For instance, I want to include the calendar week as in ISO 8601’s `yyyy-'W'ww-d`.

Extra points if this format then can be used in the system clock.

Comment: You should probably look at `defaults`. I haven't tried but there are suggestions which claimed to be working in this [discussions.apple.com thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254316210)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint and link from @aivar-paalberg helped a lot.

The date format settings are stored in the hidden file `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`. Values can be queried with `defaults` in Terminal.app and also be changed using `defaults write`.

### Getting

```bash
% defaults find AppleICU
Found 1 keys in domain 'Apple Global Domain': {
    AppleICUDateFormatStrings =     {
        1 = "y-MM-dd";
        2 = "y-MM-dd";
    };
}
```

`1` is *short*, `2` is *medium*, `3` is *long* and `4` is *full* in the [CLDR date formats](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/43/summary/en.html#562f98c4c6b2e321) (with precision to the calendar day).

### Setting

```bash
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleICUDateFormatStrings -dict-add "1" "yyyyMMdd"
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleICUDateFormatStrings -dict-add "2" "d. MMM ’yy"
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleICUDateFormatStrings -dict-add "3" "d. MMMM yyyy"
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleICUDateFormatStrings -dict-add "4" "EEEE 'KW'ww, d. MMMM yyyy"
```

Unfortunately, System Settings will not show an example result in the dropdown if it differs from the predefined formats:
[image: empty dropdown]

For English-language locales alone, the formats will default to a number of variants, as of CLDR v43:

- *short* with month number:

  - `M/d/yy` default = US
  - `d-M-yy` MV
  - `d/M/y` HK, ZW
  - `d/M/yy` AU, JM, SG
  - `d/MM/yy` NZ
  - `dd.MM.y` CH
  - `dd/MM/y` int., AE, GB
  - `dd/MM/yy` BE, BW, MZ, IN
  - `y-MM-dd` CA, SE
  - `y/MM/dd` ZA
  - ISO 8601, shortest formats:

    - `yyyyDDD` ordinal day of the year
    - `yyyyMMdd` day of the month of the year
    - `YYYY'W'wwe` day of the week of the year
    - `yyMMdd` and `yy-MM-dd` with implied century were supported before the 2004 revision.
- *medium* with abbreviated month name or number:

  - `MMM d, y` default = US
  - `d MMM y` int., AE, GB
  - `d/MM/y` NZ
  - `dd MMM y` BE, BW, MT, ZA
  - `dd MMM,y` ZW
  - `dd-MM-y` MV
  - `dd-MMM-y` BZ, IN, PK
  - ISO 8601:

    - `yyyy-DDD`
    - `yyyy-MM-dd`
    - `YYYY-'W'ww-e`
- *long* with complete month name:

  - `MMMM d, y` default = US
  - `d MMMM y` int., AE, GB, MV
  - `dd MMMM y` BW, BZ, MT, ZA, ZW
- *full* with day of the week:

  - `EEEE, MMMM d, y` default = US
  - `EEEE d MMMM y` IE, MV
  - `EEEE, d MMMM y` int., AE, GB
  - `EEEE, d MMMM, y` IN
  - `EEEE, dd MMMM y` BW, BZ, ZA, ZW

Apple / ICU supports all [Date Field Symbols](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) from UTS #35.

PS: I assume those `AppleICUDateFormatStrings` are used internally as the default `template` somewhere in [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).